# VideoView/MediaPlayer stop on last frame

Tags: android, video

is it possible to stop a video on its last frame? I am using the code below:

```
VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.menu_video);

final String uriPath = "android.resource://com.my.project/raw/myvideo"

Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
video.setVideoURI(uri);
```

I've tried to load the video from the sd card, to pause it in a completion listener and to find out something in the web... Now I am thinking about hiding it and using an ImageView as "fake" last Frame. Does anyone know a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last frame of a video you can skip to its end by using:

```
video.seekTo(video.getDuration());
```

Comment: This will skip to the last keyframe of the video, which will probably be different from the last frame.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you must register listner like this:

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
```

second:

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion called");
    this.finish();
}
```

and you should implement **OnCompletionListener** in your class

Comment: Thanks - I display the video in a videoView, which is part of the contentView of my activity. I don't want to finish the whole Activtiy but just the video...

Comment: where are you display video ? what kind of view ?

Comment: I use a [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) - which should be a wrapper of MediaPlayer...